# Can we build two towers of equal height, having $n$ cubes with edges $1,2,3,\dots,n$ centimetres respectively?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This is a problem i found on number theory and i'm having trouble with. The following is my attempt to solve it.

We want $n$ cubes, that will make up two towers of volume $V$ and height $h$. I suppose that the towers will have cubic shape, since all foundations are cubes, thus $V=h^3$. So,

$$1+2^3+3^3+4^3+\dots+n^3=2V \implies \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^3 = 2h^3 \implies \bigg[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\bigg]^2 = 2h^3 \implies $$

$$\implies n^2(n^2+2n+1)=8h^3 \implies n^4+2n^3+n^2-8h^3=0$$

This last equation has no solution (in $\mathbb{Z}$), so the problem has no answer. Something tells me i'm completely wrong and that the problem has an answer.. I can't figure it out. Help, advice? Thanks in advance.

**Update**

So obviously i was wrong. What i did now.. The number of cubes ($n$) when divisible by 2, in order to fill the height of the two towers equally, must be a Natural number. Thus

$$\frac{1+2+3+4+\dots+n}{2} \implies \frac{n(n+1)}{4}$$

We have to make sure that $4|n(n+1)$. And $n(n+1)$ will be the height of each of the towers. This happens for $n=3,4,7,\dots$ as Robert Israel pointed out.

Comment: Why do you assume the tower must be a cube?  I would have thought you could make a "tower" simply by stacking up an arbitrary collection of cubes.  So the problem is simply to partition the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ into two subsets with equal sums.

Comment: Hmm. You're right. I don't know why. I just thought it should be like a cube.. I see your answer below. Now i have to see how to find $n$.

Comment: You haven't made them equal volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the first few cases....

[image]

[image]

[image]